# Can't install SqlServer PowerShell module 21.1.18256: PackageManagement\Install-Package : Access is denied

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have servers which have no access to the Internet so I have an internal PSRepository.  I've downloaded the current SqlServer module (21.1.18256) and published it to my internal repo.  I've installed it on five servers.  On the sixth, I get:

```
> Install-module -name SqlServer -Repository JLP -AllowClobber
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Access is denied
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1772 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand,Mic
   rosoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

I've never seen this before and have no idea where to start.

I'm running PowerShell (5.1) as admin.  Versions are:

```
> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.4583
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.4583
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

**UPDATE**

I had older versions on my repo: 21.1.18121 and 21.0.17199.  I tried installing and got the Access is Denied message.  Then I tried 21.0.17199 using

```
Install-module -name SqlServer -Repository JLP -AllowClobber -RequiredVersion 21.0.17199
```

and it worked.

**UPDATE 2**

I have downloaded other versions to my repo and tried them.

```
21.0.17279 failed to install.
21.0.17262 failed to install.
21.0.17240 installed.
```

Comment: I experience the same thing. Oddly adding -Verbose to the command to see if I could troubleshoot further actually caused it to install. I don't like it, but in case it works for others I post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Scope CurrentUser
```

source:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-7.1

If it works with your current login, then talk to someone about getting permission to update the local machine module folder.

Comment: Good suggestion.  Unfortunately, it gave me exactly the same error.  I also tried that version of the command with PowerShell **not** running as Administrator with the same result.

Comment: Have you checked for write permission to folders in $env:PSModulePath? I would personally try installing the module to a different location to verify I can get it working then worry about installing to a default folder. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/installing-a-powershell-module?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: I haven't but I'm a local Administrator and running as Administrator so that **shouldn't** be an issue.  Other people use the server and I don't want each person to have to install their own copy.  Plus, I can install other modules using that format of command.  And I've been able to install an earlier version.